# How to calculate Month wise Net amount but with some filter conditions in Power BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data set where I have field as Query1[BILLYEARMONTH], Query1[LT_HT] and Query1[NET BILLING AMOUNT]. Now in my field

Query1[LT_HT] values are as follow: 1). HT 2). EHT 3). Three Phase 4). Single Phase. In the field Query1[BILLYEARMONTH], i have values of year/month as 202202, 202203, 202204 and so on. Field Query1[NET BILLING AMOUNT] is my amount to be calculated.

Now i want condition in DAX as:

When Query1[BILLYEARMONTH] = 202203, the Query1[NET BILLING AMOUNT] will be picked based on Query1[LT_HT] =  "HT"  & "EHT" and   Query1[NET BILLING AMOUNT] for Query1[LT_HT] ="Single Phase" & "Three Phase" should be from the next month which is for example "202204".

That means, Current month should consider Amount with filters as "HT" and "EHT" + Amount with filter as "Single Phase" and "Three Phase" from the next month.

How to achieve the same, i tried a lot but not getting the desired result. Please help.

I have tried the below formula, but no luck.

Amount for Feb_22 = CALCULATE(SUM(Query1[NET_BILLING_AMOUNT]), (Query1[BILLYEARMONTH] = 202203 && (Query1[LT_HT] = "Single Phase" || Query1[LT_HT] = "Three Phase")) || (Query1[BILLYEARMONTH] = 202202 && (Query1[LT_HT] = "HT" || Query1[LT_HT] = "EHT")))

Comment: what do you mean by current month like in today case it is 202306 ?

Comment: Current month means, if for current month I want to calculate Net billing Amount then, it should consider Net billing amount with fitlers as LT_HT = "HT" and "EHT" for this month which is 202306 and Net billing amount for LT_HT = "Single Phase" and "Three Phase" from the upcoming month i.e., 202307. Thus, my final Net billing amount will be addition of these two Net Billing amount.

Comment: Basically, i want to consider Net Billing amount for field LT_HT = "HT" and "EHT" for current month (202306) and field LT_HT = "Single Phase" and "Three Phase" from next month (202307). the final value for current month (202306) should be the addition of these two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

You have to follow this

1. Create an index column (PowerBi -> Transform Data)
2. Create a measure for monthly_wise

   Monthy_Billing_Amount =
   // GET THE CURRENT AMOUNT
   VAR CURRENT_AMOUNT =
   CALCULATE(
   SUM(Sheet1[NET BILLING AMOUNT]),
   Sheet1[LT_HT] IN {"HT", "EHT"}
   )
   // Rank months from 1 to 5
   VAR RANK_MONTHS_VAL =
   RANKX(
   ALL(Sheet1),
   CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[BILLYEARMONTH])),,
   ASC
   )
   VAR NEXT_RANK_MONTH = RANK_MONTHS_VAL + 1
   VAR NEXT_AMOUNT =
   CALCULATE(
   SUM(Sheet1[NET BILLING AMOUNT]),
   FILTER(
   ALL(Sheet1),
   Sheet1[Index] = NEXT_RANK_MONTH
   ),
   Sheet1[LT_HT] IN {"Single Phase", "Three Phase"}

   )
   RETURN CURRENT_AMOUNT + NEXT_AMOUNT

[image]

Comment: Final_amount =                                                                                                                   
 VAR CurrentMonthAmount =
     CALCULATE(
        SUM(Query1[NET_BILLING_AMOUNT]),
        (Query1[LT_HT] = "HT" || Query1[LT_HT] = "EHT") &&
        Query1[BILLYEARMONTH] = 202202
    )
VAR NextMonthAmount =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Query1[NET_BILLING_AMOUNT]),
        (Query1[LT_HT] = "Single Phase" || Query1[LT_HT] = "Three Phase") &&
        Query1[BILLYEARMONTH] = 202203
    )
RETURN
    CurrentMonthAmount + NextMonthAmount

Comment: Is this what you want me to do?

Comment: Create an index column first then create a measure

Comment: FINAL_AMOUNT = // GET THE CURRENT AMOUNT VAR CURRENT_AMOUNT = CALCULATE( SUM(Sheet1[NET BILLING AMOUNT]), Sheet1[LT_HT] IN {"HT", "EHT"} ) // Rank months from 1 to 5 VAR RANK_MONTHS_VAL = RANKX( ALL(Sheet1), CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[BILLYEARMONTH])),, ASC ) VAR NEXT_RANK_MONTH = RANK_MONTHS_VAL + 1 VAR NEXT_AMOUNT = CALCULATE( SUM(Sheet1[NET BILLING AMOUNT]), FILTER( ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[Index] = NEXT_RANK_MONTH ), Sheet1[LT_HT] IN {"Single Phase", "Three Phase"}

) RETURN CURRENT_AMOUNT + NEXT_AMOUNT

Comment: copy this code into your measure

Comment: Hi Muhammad, first of all thank you very much! I tried something as below:

Comment: Final_Amt = VAR CURRENT_AMOUNT = CALCULATE( SUM(Query1[NET_BILLING_AMOUNT]), Query1[LT_HT] IN {"HT", "EHT"} ) 
VAR RANK_MONTHS_VAL = RANKX( ALL(Query1), CALCULATE(MAX(Query1[BILLYEARMONTH])),, ASC ) 
VAR NEXT_RANK_MONTH = RANK_MONTHS_VAL + 1 
VAR NEXT_AMOUNT = CALCULATE( SUM(Query1[NET_BILLING_AMOUNT]), FILTER( ALL(Query1), Query1[INDEXING] = NEXT_RANK_MONTH ), Query1[LT_HT] IN {"Single Phase", "Three Phase"} ) RETURN CURRENT_AMOUNT + NEXT_AMOUNT

Comment: This has given me desired result for the first month i.e., "202202", but for rest of the months till "202305", it shows net billing amount only for "HT" and "EHT". It seems condition for "Single Phase" and "Three Phase" for the next month is getting skipped.

Comment: Kindly give desired result in a pictorial format

Comment: Can i have your mail id? I am unable to paste screenshots here...

Comment: yes sure, muhammadali962410@gmail.com